# Как упростить работу с html и sass

Tags: html, css, phpstorm, sass, scss

Нужно: в каком то редакторе текста, открыв там **html** файл и при клике на определенный стиль открывать файл **sass**. Так, к примеру в phpStorm, клик по стилю откроет файл стилей **css**, а нужно открыть **sass** файл

Данные для примера: **html** страница, к ней подключаем файл стилей, `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">`
в теле страницы имеем `<p class="logo__link">crm web-application</p>`
нужно, что бы по клику по `logo__link` перешли в файл `main.sass` и сразу открылся стиль по которому нажимали.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.sass">
</head>
<body>

<div class="logo">
    <p class="logo__link">TEXT</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Сам работаю в phpStorm, но подойдет ответ для любого редактора...
возможно в каком либо редакторе, можно так настроить или подключить плагин какой нибудь...
подойдет вариант и с SCSS

добавил в HTML строку:     `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.sass">`
теперь phpStorm выдает варианты перехода если корень стиля по BEM `logo`, это уже хорошо, идеально было бы переходить в подстили по BEM `logo__image`, так как в SASS там стиль просто `&__image`

вопрос пока открыт...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Теоретически, это всё настроить можно и в phpStorm

Comment: хотелось бы услышать практический ответ ))